# how to identify text box in Selenium Web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Greetings!!
I am trying to identify “text box” in selenium web driver for my testing but, I am not able to identify it. Every combination I try it gives me error. 
Read all the blogs no luck for me. However I am able to identify text box and able to enter value using selenium IDE with ‘xpath’:  //input[@class='amInput55p portlet-form-input-field']. Tried converting IDE code to Java/JUnit  4/WebDriver  didn’t work.

```
<div id="portal-content" class="content" style="height: 99%;">
<img onerror="alert('[POP.016.0041] Please deploy wm_cafshared.war.')" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;" alt="" src="/wm_cafshared/ui/img/blank.gif">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/wm_cafshared/dyn/j/ui/js/controls/standard/dialog.js?l=en_US&v=100922171045" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:module" class="vModule"></div>
<form id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/meta/default/amaccountmaintenance___search/0000340233?wmp_tv=%2fSearch%2fdefault.view&wmp_rt=action&wmp_tc=340233&__ns=wmp340233" method="POST" name="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:breadcrumb" class="ambreadcrumb"></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:blockPanel42" class="amRowGutterMargin2"></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:amScreenWrapper">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:blockPanel3" class="amApplicationTitleBar">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:blockPanel" class="clear"></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:content">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel2" class="amApplicationWrapper" style="height: 30px;">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel32" class="amContentWrapper">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel4" class="amRowGutterMargin6 "></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel133" class="amRequiredModule">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel134" class="amTitle">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel135" class="clear"></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:promptFieldID" class="amPromptFields" style="">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:promptFieldID__content">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel61" class="amRowGutterMargin2"></div>
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:requiredFieldsMsgPanel" class="amInfoMessagesPanel readonly">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel137" class="amPromptFieldColumn50p ">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel139" class="amField100p">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel140" class="amOptionalPromptLabel">
<div id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:blockPanel145" class="amInputWrapper50p">
<input id="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:txtAccountNumID" class="amInput55p portlet-form-input-field" type="text" onkeypress="allowNumber(event);" onkeydown="var searchButton = 'jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:btnSearch'; if((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) { document.getElementById(searchButton).click(); return false; }else return true;" maxlength="10" value="" name="jsfwmp340233:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:txtAccountNumID">
</div> - this is tag for text box
```

Tried all combinations xpath, cssSector didn’t work. 
    -AmSearch.findElement(By.id("jsfwmp33948:htmlForm1:importView:htmlForm:txtAccountNumID"));  (The Id for the text box is dynamic, predicted next number and provided in this as well)

- `AmSearch.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='portal-content']/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/input"));`
- `AmSearch.findElement(By.cssSelector("id$=txtAccountNumID"));`
- `AmSearch.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='amInput55p portlet-form-input-field']"))`

For all option getting errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='portal-content']/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/input"}
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_21'
Session ID: 4b36db92-7d80-43a9-aea4-309270ee77e0`enter code here`
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`enter code here`
```

Please help me getting pass through this. All the help are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your cssSelector is close.  Try this one:
`By.cssSelector(input[id$='txtAccountNumID'])`

Comment: No luck. Eclipse throw error 'Invalid char constant' for txtAccountNumID. added "" still same error. AmSearch.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id$='txtAccountNumID']"));

Comment: Oh, yes sorry, I was writing that on the fly.  Is your element in an IFrame?

Comment: Yes. It's in Iframe. <iframe id="amMainFrame" class="amMainFrame" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="178" frameborder="0" src="/meta/default/amaccountmaintenance___search/0000340255" name="amMainFrame">

Comment: That's your problem then.  You need to switch to the IFrame by doing driver.switchTo.frame(IFrameElement)

Comment: Thank you Sir. It worked, now able to identify and proceed further. this helped a lot. AmSearch.switchTo().frame("amMainFrame");